# pyfluidsynth running on RaspberryPi errors

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, midi

I'm trying to play midi sounds from my python program on a RaspberryPi, however when trying to initialise fluidsynth, it errrors:

```
>>> import fluidsynth
>>> import time
>>> fs = fluidsynth.Synth()
>>> fs.start()
```

Causes the following errors:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.9
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2012 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot lock down 82278944 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
fluidsynth: error: Failed to connect to Jack server.
```

I think the final message can be fixed by starting the Jack server, however I can't fix the

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
```

errors

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

The default fluidsynth settings apparently are not appropriate for the Raspberry Pi.

Change the [audio driver settings](http://fluidsynth.sourceforge.net/api/index.html#CreatingAudioDriver) so that uses `alsa` instead of `jack`.

If you don't know how to do this in Python, start fluidsynth manually from the command line, and tell your Python program to output to fluidsynth's port.

Comment: I had trouble getting fluidsynth from the command line to work. Do you know how to change the audio driver settings in python?

Comment: No. Try `fluidsynth -a alsa -m alsa_seq`.

Comment: Ah in python: fs.start(driver='alsa')

Comment: now it comes up with: fluidsynth: error: There is no preset with bank number 0 and preset number 0 in SoundFont 1

Comment: I guess you didn't load a sound font.

Comment: I did load the soundfont. I've tried another soundfont and it didn't come up with the error, but there was no sound :(